# « Quel est votre adresse ? » et « C'est quoi, votre adresse ? »

Tags: traduction, questions

Les deux questions, sont-elles correcte? Aussi, l'une est-elle plus ou moins formelle que l'autre?

Je me suis posé ces questions en regardant la phrase "What's your address?" et essayant de la traduire.

Si j'ai fait des fautes, n'hésitez pas à les corriger.

Comment: Si quelqu'un a des meilleurs tags, ajoutez-les s'il vous plaît

Comment: Il n'y a pas de faute évidente en tout cas :)

Comment: @Random merci! C'est toujours bon de l'entendre.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

La première est légèrement erronée (faute d'accord) mais la formule est la bonne; c'est celle qui est utilisée à l'écrit et en français parlé soutenu ou courant :

> « **Quelle** est votre adresse ? »

La deuxième est correcte mais ne respecte pas le « bon usage » à l'écrit. Elle est donc d'un registre beaucoup plus relâché et ne se rencontre qu'à l'oral, où c'est certainement la forme la plus courante aujourd'hui :

> « C'est quoi, votre adresse ? »

Si on tutoie son interlocuteur, la question sera bien sûr :

> « C'est quoi, ton adresse ? »

D'autres traductions plus ou moins fidèles, toujours d'un registre courant ou familier, peuvent être :

> « Je peux avoir ton adresse ? »
>
> « Tu peux me donner ton adresse ? »
>
> « Tu me donnes ton adresse ? »
>
> « Qu'est-ce que c'est ton adresse ? »
>
> « C koi ton @ ? » (écrit, langage « SMS »)

À l'opposé, dans un registre formel, on pourrait entendre :

> « Puis-je avoir votre adresse ? »
>
> « Pourriez-vous m'indiquer votre adresse ? »
>
> « Auriez-vous l'amabilité de m'indiquer votre adresse ? »
>
> « Est-ce que je peux me permettre de vous demander votre adresse ? »

Comment: Merci! Je n'ai pas vu l'erreur, mais je suis d'accord.

Comment: Vraiment relâché, le registre, surtout à l'écrit.

Comment: @LaurentS. exact.

Comment: Oui, je n'ecrirais pas le 2eme.

Comment: Aussi, si vous allez utiliser une forme familière telle que "c'est quoi...", vous utiliseriez peut-etre plutot "ton" que "votre" dans la suite. "c'est quoi" est presque une petite aggression, alors pas besoin d'utiliser un "votre" de politesse après ca.

Comment: @Frank Oui, j'aurais c'est vrai pu mettre « c'est quoi ton adresse ». Je ne considère cependant pas « c'est quoi » comme étant nécessairement « presque une petite aggression » sauf si le ton est inamical et bien sûr en fonction de la demande. « C'est quoi ton problème ? » peut être par exemple très agressif. Le tutoiement n'y arrange rien, bien au contraire.

Comment: @jiliagre: pour moi, je peux sentir un peu d'agression suivant le ton utilisé, et parce que oui, ca évoque "c'est quoi ton problème?". Evidemment, si un ami me posait la question, je ne verrais pas d'aggression. Mais avec "votre" dans la suite, je trouve que "c'est quoi" est vraiment trop familier, je range cette tournure dans un registre de language pas soutenu du tout. Je suis sans doute trop sensible, ou vieux jeu, ou les deux, mais Laurent allait un peu dans ce sens aussi.

Comment: @Frank On surestime souvent le niveau de langage utilisé habituellement par les français, dans la vie de tous les jours. Par exemple, beaucoup de personnes pensent que la première personne du pluriel est encore couramment employée dans le français parlé usuel alors qu'elle a quasiment disparu à l'oral, en dehors de contextes formels.

Comment: @jiliagre. Je suis bien d'accord. Mais surtout, je me rends compte qu'offrir une traduction pour une petite phrase en anglais sans contexte est en fait difficile. Le contexte est important, le ton... et d'ailleurs, le ton est d'habitude perdu sur l'internet, un obstacle supplémentaire. Et la langue change tout le temps, et de facon différente suivant les endroits...